# Replace email with full name in Auth Menu on asp.net react project template

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I create a React App using Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET React Project Template. I was able to to modify the project to add some custom fields during registration. Those customer fields include First & Last Name.

I'd like to replace the email that is displayed on every page within the navigation menu:[image]

I managed to successfully replace it on the Razor pages that are scaffolded in the Identity Framework.
[image]

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it on the React side of things. Any documentation you can point me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you post code with the changes that are different from the regular spa template that would help

Comment: I followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio to get as far as I did. But when it came time to modify the react components I couldn't find any documentation to guide me. I would post the code but the changes are significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `ClientApp/src/components/api-authorization/LoginMenu.js` and change `populateState` method to:

```js
async populateState() {
    const [isAuthenticated, user] = await Promise.all([authService.isAuthenticated(), authService.getUser()])
    this.setState({
        isAuthenticated,
        userName: user && `${user.given_name} ${user.family_name}`
    });
}
```

To map the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties to `given_name` and `family_name` claims you can use `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`:

```cs
public class AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.LastName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.BirthDate, user.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ClaimValueTypes.Date));

        return identity;
    }
}
```

And in `Startup.cs` add:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Assuming you have defined `ApplicationUser` as:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you recommending that I modify populateState and call my own API to get the user information I need? The user doesn't have the claims that include first & last name. Looks like the code is part of a NuGet package. I'm trying to find where to replace the code in order to include it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't come populated. It's almost like I need to modify the api to include those claims. it maybe something as simple as configuring DI to include the custom object I've created which includes the custom fields. Currently only working on the server side and doesn't pass it to React.

Comment: Updated my answer, should be `user.given_name` and `user.family_name`.

Comment: The JSON only includes:
{
   amr,
   auth_time,
   idp,
   name: <my email>,
   preferred_username: <my email again>,
   sid,
   sub
}

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Under node_modules/oidc-client/index.d.ts there is a TS Interface that include given_name & family_name as well as birthdate (another custom field I added). In my claims I called them FirstName, LastName & DateOfBirth which probably the reason it's not mapping it.

Is there a way to map those fields?

Comment: I added instructions for how to map FirstName and LastName to claims.

Comment: Dimitris Maragkos, you are the man!!! I would give you 5-Stars if I could. Instead, I will give you the solution check mark. Thank you (as I take a bow and tip my hat off to you).